# Perforce P4 C++ API Client creation

Tags: c++, api, command

I'm working on an application using the Perforce C++ API, this is how i create a new client:

```
OutputClient ui;

char* argv[1] = {"newClient"};

client.SetArgv(1,argv);
client.Run("client", &ui);
client.Set("newClient");
```

It's the same as using the command:

```
p4 client newClient
```

That creates the client (if it doesn't exist) and sets the workspace(client root) to my Visual Studio project directory.

Is there any way to specify or set the client root through p4 commands or using the API?
And also when I use the "client" command it always opens  that annoying form, is there any way to stop that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

The [help for `p4 client`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/client.html) says the default client root is the current working directory. Perhaps that's how it's choosing your Visual Studio project directory.

From the command line, you can write the clientspec (including the desired root) to a file and then use `p4 client -i < clientspec.txt` to upload it to the server. The C++ API supports doing the same thing without a temp file, by [overriding `ClientUser::InputData()`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api/03_methods.html#1063683).

`p4 client -i` is particularly useful in combination with `p4 client -o clientname > clientspec.txt`, because you can read an existing clientspec, modify it, and write it back to the server. (Of course, it's not an atomic read/modify/write.)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed to change or edit the client root! One more thing, you know that every time the client command is called, it opens the temp form file to edit the client spec, do you know how can I disable or stop that behavior?

Comment: The `-i` option should prevent `p4 client` from opening an editor, and it gives your program complete control over the clientspec. But if you don't want to use `-i`, setting the `P4EDITOR` environment variable to a command of your choosing can probably do what you want.

Comment: You are right the -i option prevents the command from opening the editor, if I first set the P4CLIENT variable to the client name I defined in the clientspec.txt. Thanks!